# Question regarding Cramer's rule proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that Cramer's rule can be shown from:

$$Ax=b\iff x=A^{-1}b\iff x=\frac{adj(A)}{det(A)}\cdot b$$

I do understand that $adj(A)\cdot b$ is equal to calculating the determinant when replacing the $i$-th column of $A$.

But why we are doing it for all the columns of $A$?

Comment: Because each column $i$ gives you solution of one of the components $x_i$.

Comment: @KittyL yes, so it is not directly from $adj(A)\cdot b$ ?

Comment: This actually gives you the whole vector $x$, as Andreas pointed out. I am not sure what you meant by "doing it for all the columns of $A$" in this case.

Comment: @KittyL I meant the we need to go over all the columns of $A$ and each time replace one by the $b$ vector

Comment: For computation, if you use the other formula $\det(A_i)/\det(A)$ where $A_i$ means replacing the $i$th column by $b$, then you need to do it every time for all columns of $A$. Cramer's rule is good for theoretical proof, but not very efficient for computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you wrote "I do understand that $adj(A)\cdot b\ \dots$" it should be ""I do understand that the $i$-th component of the vector $adj(A)\cdot b\ \dots$".  If you want the whole vector (i.e., if you want all the $x_i$'s, not just one of them), then you have to do this for all $i$.